# Android remote device administration with specifics

Tags: android

I have the following requirement for a client, could you advise me the correct direction.

Client wants and Android device which is fully controlled by device remote admin features. Where I need to accomplish following features.

- Lock Play store so users cannot install apps
- User access certain apps in certain time of the day
- User should be able to use the phone only a specific.

All these parameters, can be changed from a remote admin panel.

Could you provide me with some article or something which helps me do that.
I see this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: None of that is possible through the device administration APIs or any other documented and supported mechanism.

Comment: How abt rooting android building a custom rom.. How to companies when they provide android deices to their field employees does these kind of things.